# Edited vs emitted - why one t vs two t's

Tags: orthography

Why does "edited" have one "t" and  and "emitted" has two? "Edit" and "emit" are so similar in spelling and pronunciation.  I keep wanting to type "editted" for some reason.

Comment: When you figure that out, maybe you can do *clarinetist/clarinettist* for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where the stress is. If the stress is on the final syllable, the consonant will usually be doubled.

Answer (score 1):

Because the stress is different.  *Emit* is stressed on the second syllable, *edit* on the first.